# CocoaPods version control, must use pod install when cloning repo

Tags: git, version-control, ios8, xcode6, cocoapods

I have a question about using CocoaPods and working with version control. I have my project on a repo at GitLab. But if someone wants to clone that repo and work on it they have to use the `pod install` command. I thought that if you push you project with pods to a repo you don't have to use `pod install` when cloning it. Or is it something I have done wrong? This is how the current `.gitignore` file looks:

```
xcschememanagement.plist
Pods-AFNetworking.xcscheme
Pods.xcscheme
Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
```

Can this be the cause of the my problem?

So my question is; how do I make it so that you don't have to run the `pod install` command each time you clone the repo or is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are different pros and cons of checking the `Pods` directory into source control vs not doing it. This information is available in [this section](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control) of the Cocoapod guides. Like you've pointed out one benefit is not having to run `pod install` after cloning the repository

Comment: Yes but what am I doing wrong, since I have to run pod install after each clone?

Comment: It seems weird that you are ignoring some parts of the files that cocoapods will install, does removing does ignores help?

Comment: nope it didn't seem to helt when I removed those files from my git ignore file